# How to find the union of two Int16Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, binary-data, typed-arrays

I have two Int16Arrays:

```
const a = new Int16Array([ 0, 0, 0, 1 ])
const b = new Int16Array([ 1, 0, 0, 0 ])
```

I need to find a way to unify these two arrays, so that I receive an output like so:

```
Int16Array(4) [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ]
```

the length of the two arrays will always be the same, and all indexes will be either 0 or 1 for both arrays. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: The boolean `|` operator is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const a = new Int16Array([ 0, 0, 1, 1 ])
const b = new Int16Array([ 1, 0, 1, 0 ])

const result = new Int16Array(a.map((e, i) => e | b[i]))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you

Comment: Please upvote @Pointy. I first had a more complicated solution for the condition instead of his _e | b[i]_.